# Iterator vs index for quicksort implementation

Tags: c++, performance, indexing, iterator, quicksort

Why do the following quicksort implementations have a large difference in performance? The implementation using iterators takes twice as much time as the one using indices; at both -O0 and -03 optimization. A similar effect is seen with mergesort. The comparison is run on a std::vector.

Quicksort using iterators:

```
template<typename It>
It QuickSortPartitionUtil(It begin, It last) {
  auto pivot = last;
  auto current = begin;
  for(auto it = begin; it < last; ++it) {
    if(*it < *pivot) {
      std::iter_swap(current, it);
      ++current;
    }
  }
  std::iter_swap(current, last);
  return current;
}

template<typename It>
void QuickSortUtil(It begin, It last) {
  if(begin < last) {
    auto partition = QuickSortPartitionUtil(begin, last);
    QuickSortUtil(begin, std::prev(partition, 1));
    QuickSortUtil(std::next(partition, 1), last);
  }
}

template<typename It>
void QuickSort(It begin, It end) {
    QuickSortUtil(begin, std::prev(end));
}
```

Quicksort using indices:

```
template<typename T>
int QuickSortPartition(std::vector<T>& to_sort, int start, int last) {
    T pivot = to_sort[last];
    int i = start;
    for(int j = start; j < last; j++) {
        if(to_sort[j] < pivot) {
            std::swap(to_sort[i], to_sort[j]);
            i++;
        }
    }
    std::swap(to_sort[last], to_sort[i]);
    return i;
}

template<typename T>
void QuickSortUtil(std::vector<T>& to_sort, int start, int last) {
    if(start < last) {
        int p = QuickSortPartition(to_sort, start, last);
        QuickSortUtil(to_sort, start, p-1);
        QuickSortUtil(to_sort, p+1, last);
    }
}

template<typename T>
void QuickSort(std::vector<T>& to_sort) {
    int v = to_sort.size();
    QuickSortUtil(to_sort, 0, v-1);
}
```

main test function:

```
int main() {

    const int size_to_sort{10000};
    std::vector<int> to_sort(size_to_sort);
    std::random_device rd;

    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> dist(0, size_to_sort);
    int duration = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        std::cout << "Iteration: " << i << std::endl;
        std::generate(to_sort.begin(), to_sort.end(), [&](){return dist(gen);});

        auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
        // QuickSort(to_sort);
        QuickSort(to_sort.begin(), to_sort.end());
        auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();

        assert(std::is_sorted(to_sort.begin(), to_sort.end()));
        duration += duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start).count();
    }

    std::cout << "Time taken: " << duration << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OK I can see the difference, but on my PC and my gcc version difference is only 13%. But for clang quite the same difference but in opposite. Looks like some optimization issue.

Comment: @Slava This is true even at O0? I am seeing around 35% differences at both O0 and O3 in gcc. EDIT: if you can post the answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I used O2, with O3 iterator variant is faster (but single digit percents) on gcc

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219713/discussion-on-question-by-vss2sn-iterator-vs-index-for-quicksort-implementation).